# Are Greg Irwin's finger fitness exercises really useful to increase guitar players' skills?

Tags: guitar, classical-guitar, exercises

I'm wondering: does doing exercises of the book [Finger Fitness - The Art of Finger Control](https://www.fluteworld.com/product/finger-fitness-art-of-finger-control/) by Lorraine C. and Gregory G. Irwin really help to increase finger dexterity and flexibility and is it useful for guitar players as suggested in the description?

> You will be able to master your finger control and tune your brain in with the movements of your hands. This hand control is critical if you are a musician or magician in need of delicate and subtle hand/finger movements.

There are also [YouTube videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nB41RQNkBSA) available for some of the exercises.

So I'm wondering: does practicing these exercises really help guitar players?
I'm asking because I want to practice them if they are actually useful.

Comment: Looks like they probably are helpful but it also looks like you could basically get the same finger workout while also learning to play guitar. If you spend a lot of time in situations where you could do these exercises and couldn't play guitar, then maybe they would help without being a waste of time. But I would never put down my guitar to do these exercises, I would just work on guitar exercises.

Comment: I saw the images in the fluteworld link and thought: "Was that the guy I saw on The Tonight Show in the late 80s?"  [Yes, it was.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDr7NuEcZls)  One thing those exercises are good for is doing the kind of performance he did there.   (Jump to about 7:00.)

Comment: @Theodore I saw the video and it was quite interesting!

Answer (score 1):

Some guitar players report improvements in their finger control and flexibility after practicing the exercises. The exercises should be used as a supplement to regular guitar practice and performed correctly with proper technique to avoid injury. Seeking guidance from a qualified guitar teacher or hand therapist may be helpful to ensure that you are performing the exercises safely and effectively.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is Greg Irwin who appeared on The Tonight Show. The Finger Exercise program is designed as a supplement for your guitar playing.  Of course playing the guitar will exercise your fingers and develop their ability best for guitar.
The exercises are great to do while away from guitar and also as a warmup before playing. Good Luck with your Hands.